# Google Apps Script: withSuccessHandler running without google.script.run.myFunction() running

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Within a Google Sheet, I've created an Apps Script to open an html form in a dialog. Along with some input fields on the form, there are two buttons - Save/Exit and Save/Next.

While the buttons should run different server-side functions, both should close the dialog once the server confirms receipt.  However I'm finding that the server functions are not running at all, but withSuccessHandler seems to be triggering anyway!

Abbreviated code:
**Code.gs**

```
function newProposal() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('frmBackground').setHeight(500).setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(html, 'New Proposal');
}
function saveBackground(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("hello");
  Logger.log(e);
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Project Data");
  var alast = sheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var inpCell = sheet.getRange("A" + (3+alast))
  inpCell.setValue(sheet.getRange("A" + (2+alast)).getValue()+1);
  inpCell = sheet.getRange("B" + (3+alast));
  inpCell.setValue(e.Opportunity)  
}
```

**frmBackground.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <form>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #800080;">PROJECT BACKGROUND</span></h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="height: 172px;" width="778" cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 187px;">
<p style="text-align: right;"><strong><span style="color: #800080;">Project Start Date:</span></strong></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 187px;"><input name="inp_Start" type="date" /></td>
<td style="width: 188px;"><strong><span style="color: #800080;">Opportunity ID:</span></strong></td>
<td style="width: 188px;"><input name="inp_Opportunity" size="3/" type="text" /> <strong><span style="color: #800080;">&nbsp;&nbsp;months</span></strong></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
<input type="button" value="Save and Return" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).saveBackground()"/>
<input type="button" value="Save and Continue" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).saveBackgroundNext()"/></p>
</form>
  </body>

</html>
```

What I expect to happen:
The code in saveBackground() and saveBackgroundNext() should run. The dialog should not close because I haven't yet written a return value.

What I've also tried:

- Eliminating the .withSuccessHandler and just asking the button to run
  google.script.run.saveBackground() by itself. No response.
- Creating a  section with a function in the html that tries to execute google.script.run.  No response.
- Altering the .withSuccessHandler to remove the () after close. No response, but that is expected because there is no Success message to trigger it.

Comment: 1.Explain `No response`  2. Provide execution logs: View> Executions 3. What's `e`?

Comment: No response = nothing happens, including no log.  The html simply is not running the server side function at all. e is my expected result from the form, although it's moot as long as the function doesn't run.

Comment: 1. Use `console.log()` 2. View> Executions (``html simply is not running the server side function`` You're mistaken) 3. You're not passing any argument as `e` in the form.

Comment: I'm aware that I'm not passing e.  What I'm saying is that if it did run the server-side function, the Toast would appear and I'd have a log entry saying "null" or "undefined" or maybe an error. Those things aren't happening.  I simply wasn't at that step yet. However, I did try adding (this.parentNode) to the call and I get the same result - function is not running, no toast, no Log.

Comment: wrap the `close` inside `function(){google.script.host.close()}` not sure this changes a lot but that's best practice

Comment: Where do you submit the form?

Comment: @Scott I did a quick test of your code and it seems to run fine on my end, albeit I had to remove the following line `inpCell.setValue(e.Opportunity)` ! I am able to get both the toast and undefined logged. My suggestion is to look at the console log when you press the "save and return" button and check if you see any errors?

Comment: I finally found the blocker - when I removed the <p style="text-align: center;"> tag wrapping the buttons, the form called the function. @JackBrown out of curiosity did your test include that tag when it worked?

Comment: @Scott I have seen the same behaviour as @JackBrown, with the code exactly as above, the problem is that the `e` parameter is undefined so the line that attempts to access it crashes. But I'm seeing that the server-side saveBackground() function **is** being called with the tag in place.

Comment: @scott I just removed the dots in the html files and ran it that is all..